Why is Python httpx.get or requests.get much slower than cURL for this API?
For a home automation project I am trying to pull train delay data. An API wrapper exists, with cURL examples. These work fine, but both Python's requests.get and httpx.get are slow to pull data (up to a minute for requests and about 4 seconds for httpx) but curl, or pasting a link in the browser, returns almost immediately. Why?
The internet suggested that some sites have anti-scraping protections and may throttle or block requests, as it uses HTTP1.0. On this API httpx does seem to be much faster, but nowhere near as fast as curl or the browser.
Some examples - this Python snippet takes about 4 seconds:
    import httpx
    client = httpx.Client(http2=True)
    response = client.get('https://v6.db.transport.rest/stations?query=berlin')
    print(response.text)

This takes up to a minute:
    import requests
    response = requests.get('https://v6.db.transport.rest/stations?query=berlin') 
    print(response.text)

This returns almost immediately:
    import subprocess
    command = 'curl \'https://v6.db.transport.rest/stations?query=berlin\' -s'
    result = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True, shell=True, text=True)
    print(result.stdout)
    print(result.stderr)

What's the magic here?

I can't reproduce this problem. httpx takes 0.163 seconds, requests takes 0.136 seconds, curl takes 0.158 seconds for me. Do you maybe have a proxy setup that requests and httpx respect, but curl doesn't?

Thank you for the reply - very strange - there is no proxy on my LAN, AFAIK, but your results add another potential direction to my research.

This is indeed strange. For me, requests takes ~75s without any VPN or proxy in play. However, if I utilise a VPN (I'm in UK with VPN hosted in Netherlands) then it's 0.2s. Looks as though the API considers the query origin

@SIGHUP Did you also try the other methods? (For the record, I'm trying from a Finnish origin.)

@AKX I tried from my Browser (Safari) and also curl without VPN and I get  fast responses. I've interrogated the browser's behaviour in terms of HTTP headers and tried to emulate them but no luck so far. Also, Postman gets a fast response.

So, thanks to the comment from @AKX above - here is an answer that Works For Me™. The problem is not directly caused by requests or httpx but by network connectivity - in this case IPv6. Running curl -v showed that curl was using IPv4 and forcing requests to do the same fixes the issue with the above API.
requests.packages.urllib3.util.connection.HAS_IPV6 = False

I could not find how to do this for httpx.
This solution came from Stack Overflow here which links to this one.

Glad you found a workaround! Maybe some century we'll have robustly working global IPv6...

This certainly works. I wish I fully understood why!
